# Open the directory in Nautilus of a file found with locate

Tags: nautilus, locate

After locating an .odt file I want to open the containing folder. For example i type

```
locate /home/*special*.odt
```

and find only one file. How to achieve this ? I tried to google the problem, but could not find anything.

Comment: You should quote `'/home/*special*.odt'`. Otherwise the shell may expand the pattern before it ever gets to `locate`, i.e. this could wind up getting run as `locate /home/special1.odt /home/special2.odt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the command only replies one file with its path then use the following command:

```
nautilus $(dirname "$(locate /home/*special*.odt)")
```

- `dirname` strips the last component of the path
- `nautilus ...` open nautilus file manager at the given folder

But I recommend to use it like this:

```
nautilus "$(locate /home/*special*.odt)"
```

With the file as argument, the folder will be opened AND the file is selected in nautilus.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work in my case. I think the problem is that the filename has spaces in it. Do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: @user2664856 You have to put quotes (`"`) around it, see my updated answer

Comment: Wanted to know this for a while. I find it useful to run locate in terminal then copy and paste the target (from a list of possible hits in the terminal output) into a nautilus invocation, e.g., nautilus "/target-directory/target.file" to get the target directory open (prefer to open it mysefl with gedit).